Create a list of items that are common between objects
I have these sources of data.(Technically result of some API calls).
The matching logic is Id being equal but notice that it is called different names between the them so Id and AlsoId, IdToo essentially are the same thing
$data1 = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Id='1'; Service='Service1'; Propertyx=1; Price='5' }
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Id='2'; Service='Service1'; Propertyx=1; Price='17' }
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Id='3'; Service='Service1'; Propertyx=1; Price='3' }
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Id='4'; Service='Service1'; Propertyx=1; Price='7' }
)

$data2 = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{ AlsoId='1'; Service='Service1'; Propertyx=1; Price='5' }
    [PSCustomObject]@{ AlsoId='2'; Service='Service1'; Propertyx=1; Price='17' }
    [PSCustomObject]@{ AlsoId='5'; Service='Service1'; Propertyx=1; Price='3' }
    [PSCustomObject]@{ AlsoId='6'; Service='Service1'; Propertyx=1; Price='7' }
)

$data3 = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{ IdToo='1'; Service='Service1'; Propertyx=1; Price='5' }
    [PSCustomObject]@{ IdToo='2'; Service='Service1'; Propertyx=1; Price='17' }
    [PSCustomObject]@{ IdToo='5'; Service='Service1'; Propertyx=1; Price='3' }
    [PSCustomObject]@{ IdToo='7'; Service='Service1'; Propertyx=1; Price='7' }
)

I want to create a new object just to keep the Ids that are common between all three. So in this example the result should include only "1" and "2" because they exist in all three of them.
I tried to get some ideas to adapt from this post: How to get the "difference" between two objects in another object with the same structure using powershell?
but it didn't go far. How can I achieve this in an efficient manner.

In your example, it so happens that the other properties for Id are exactly the same in both their Name and also their Values. What happens if they are not?

@Theo : Thanks, the other properties are just me being lazy and copy pasting examples of data2 and data3 from what I typed for data 1 :)   the names/value of those properties can also be different but they are not in the matching logic so you can also imagine those are also all different names and value but not in matching logic.

So, for my understanding, you want a resulting object with just the Id's they seem to have in common, even if these properties have different names and forget about the other properties? Can you give an example of this desired output?

@Theo Thanks , yes that is correct.  You can put them in anything you like, maybe a list that will have a 1 and 2 in it. So later I can use this list to "filter" those three sources of data and get all other info based on these IDs for each dataset .

For an efficient way, you might use a hahtable, see the In PowerShell, what's the best way to join two tables into one? post. To go easy, you might use the suggested JoinModule. For this, I guess you want to do this: $Data1 | Join $Data2 -on Id -eq AlsoId | Join $Data3 -on Id -eq IdToo | Select-Object Id

One option is to turn any list but the first into a hashtable - then you can iterate over the first list and quickly test whether a corresponding object exists in the other lists:
# create a list of lists
$referenceLists = $data2,$data3

# iterate over the list of lists, collect output to `$indices`
$indices = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $referenceLists.Count; $i++) {
  $list = $referenceLists[$i]
  # define a hashtable to act as an index for the current list
  $index = @{}

  foreach ($item in $list) {
    # determine the appropriate property to correlate on 
    # order of property names matter here, `Id` preferred 
    $idPropertyName = 'Id','AlsoId','IdToo' |Where-Object { $item.psobject.Properties.Match($_) } |Select-Object -First 1

    $index[$item.$idPropertyName] = $item
  }

  # output populated index
  $index
}

Now we'll have a list of hashtables, each containing all items from a particular list, indexed by the appropriate identifier.
At this point we can iterate over the first list and test correlation with each of the indices we just populated:
:outerLoop
foreach ($item in $data1) {
  foreach ($index in $indices) {
    if (-not $index.Contains($item.Id)) {
      # item not present in at least one other list -> skip
      continue outerLoop
    }

    # add additional comparison logic for further validation here
  }

  # if we reached this point it means the item was correlated (and perhaps validated) in all subsequent lists, output original item
  $item
}

The :outerLoop slug in front of the outer foreach loop is known as a control flow label, allowing us to signal continue to it, rather than simply continuing the inner loop.

Thanks,  What is Name in -Expand Name   in the first section of the code ?  It says Property "Name" couldn't be found,  also an error on  $index[$item.$idPropertyName] = $item   saying The Array Index evaluated to null

@Bohn A brainfart :-) I've removed it now

Thank you,  I now asked my question from ChatGPT and it give me an answer. I am posting it here as an answer too. Please take a look and see what you think ?

@Bohn Please avoid littering the site with AI garbage :-) FWIW the generated answer doesn't really allow for further inspection and/or validation of the associated objects, and will become prohibitively slow as the input size grows

Mathias, I really like to use your code but it still crashes on $index[$item.$idPropertyName] = $item saying The Array Index evaluated to null .   Have you ran it with the  sample data? It crashes for me.

@Bohn Did you perhaps try it with an object that doesn't have any of the listed property names as members?

Apologies, yes maybe I was doing something stupid. It does work. I will use it. Thanks. BTW do you have a sample idea for for-example what kind of code I might be able to use in this line : # add additional comparison logic for further validation here   so I know how to use it if I needed. You can come up with an imaginary situation and code example too

@Bohn That would depend entirely on the nature of the data and the questions you're trying to answer - imagine the identifier wasn't globally unique across services for example, then you might want to do a secondary check like if ($index[$item.Id].Service -ne $item.Service) { continue outerLoop <# skip non-matching services #> }

From your comments I understand you want a "List of IDs common to all 3 arrays"
This will return a array containing only the ID values found in all three
$data1.id | Where-Object { $_ -in $data2.AlsoId -and $_ -in $data3.IdToo }

This will return a array containing the complete Elements of $data1 which ID values have been found in all three
$data1 | Where-Object { $_.id -in $data2.AlsoId -and $_.id -in $data3.IdToo }


yes, so next step is to get data ( in separate variables ) out of those three data1,data2,data3 objects but filtered out to the "List of IDs common to all 3 arrays"

I'm unsure what you are asking. Could you provide an example of the kind of data you want to get? Also: $data1, $data2, $data3 | ForEach-Object { $_ | ConvertTo-Csv -NoHeader } | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Id, Service, Propertyx, Price | Select-Object -Property Id, Service, Propertyx, Price -Unique | Where-Object -Property Id -In $UniqueIdList | Group-Object -Property id -AsHashTable  
